# laptop suspend resumes immediately in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, suspend, lenovo, hibernate

I have a lenovo IdeaPad P500 laptop. While running 12.10, it suspended and resumed just fine but after upgrading to 13.04 yesterday, when I suspend it (either by closing the lid or using the "cog" icon), it goes down, and then resumes immediately. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Suspend from terminal.

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

IIRC, it will print errors. You will have something to go on.